# My monogame game won't appear at all

Tags: c#, drawing, draw, monogame

When I try to run this monogame project that I made, the only thing that shows(in a little window for some reasons, while I chose  this.graphics.ApplyChanges(); for the graphics display mode) up is a Cornflower blue screen.

Here is the drawing and load function in my monogame project:

```
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            fenetre = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds;
            fenetre.Width = graphics.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width;
            fenetre.Height = graphics.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Height;

            heros = new GameObject();
            heros.nbVie = 5;
            heros.vitesse = 5;

            //load ammos of the hero
            for (int i = 0; i < munitions.Length; i++)
            {
                munitions[i] = new GameObject();
                munitions[i].nbVie = 10;
                munitions[i].vitesse = 10;
                munitions[i].sprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("snowball");
            }
            //loads ennemy
            for (int i = 0; i < ennemy.Length; i++)
            {
                ennemy[i] = new GameObject();
                ennemy[i].nbVie = 0;
                ennemy[i].vitesse = 10;
                ennemy[i].sprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("bowser");
                ennemy[i].position = ennemy[i].sprite.Bounds;
            }

            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            heros.sprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("snowball");

            Point point = fenetre.Center;
            Rectangle pos = new Rectangle(fenetre.Center.X, fenetre.Center.Y, heros.sprite.Width, heros.sprite.Height);
            heros.position = pos;
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            //dessine les munitions du heros
            for (int i = 0; i < munitions.Length; i++)
            {
                if(munitions[i].nbVie>0)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(munitions[i].sprite, munitions[i].position, Color.White);
                }
            }

            //draws ennemy
            for (int i = 0; i < ennemy.Length; i++)
            {
                if(ennemy[i].nbVie>0)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(ennemy[i].sprite, ennemy[i].position, Color.White);
                }
            }
            //draws hero
                spriteBatch.Draw(heros.sprite, heros.position, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice that you've defined `spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);` twice, Can you explain why? And have you tried removing one of them? I also recommend using a breakpoint in the draw method and see if it reaches the inside of the if-statements. or check if any of the values are null.

Comment: Oh i didn’t notice that I defined spriteBatch twice so I removed it. Also, I tried the breakpoint in the draw methods and the compiler is able to run the draw function in the if statement but there is nothing drawn in the window

Comment: Hmm, it's noticeable that I don't see where the enemy and munitions are build. so it makes me question whether any of the values inside the draw function are null. Would you want to check that too?

Comment: I declared my ennemy and my munitions at the beginning of my code so every function can access those elements

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to see the problem right away, I think I might need to run this part of code myself at home to check what could be wrong.